# Error using the feather format package

Tags: python, pandas, feather

I am having trouble using the feather format to export data. I have installed the package using:

```
conda install feather-format -c conda-forge
```

however, when I use `pd.to_feather()` I get an error telling me to install the package (which is already installed).

> ImportError: the feather-format library is not installed
>   you can install via conda
>   conda install feather-format -c conda-forge
>   or via pip
>   pip install -U feather-format

I also tried using pyarrow, but I am getting another error, saying

> ImportError: cannot import name 'cpu_count'

Can you please tell what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem using `conda install feather-format -c conda-forge` It worked just fine.

Comment: This sounds like you may have an outdated or broken `pyarrow` version in your conda environment. Uninstall it and reinstall it through `conda`.

Comment: @xhochy Thank you, apparently this was the problem. I've uninstalled and installed again both the feather and arrow packages and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Feather has found a new home in the pyarrow module**, so no need to install Feather anymore.

I can recommend you to have a look at [Feather format update: Whence and Whither?](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/feather-arrow-future/), that explains why and in general is a nice little walk through of the changes plus a benchmark between the pyarrow and legacy feather module - interesting since we all use the format for performance reasons :-)